# Using decimal values for pixel sizes in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

In android values xml folder, creating values with decimal values is meaningful or not?

```
<dimen name="list_margin_left">7.25dp</dimen>
<dimen name="width">40.3dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Yes it is useful you can access it in multiple places easily you can manage your code.for code management it is useful :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is :

- in MDPI, 1 dp = 1 pixel
- in XHDPI, 1 dp = 2 pixels

So using 7.5 dp is the only way to get something 15 pixels large in XHDPI.